# Почему у меня не выходит это сделать?

Tags: c++, строки

у меня есть строка и я до нее хочу додать еще пару стрингов? Но у меня не выходит. Потому что плюс наверное не перегружен я правильно понимаю? 
Так работает.

```
wstring expression = L"My name is Kolia";
    expression.append(L"I am form Ukiraine. ");
    expression.append(L"I study at MIT univerisy. ");
    expression.append(L"I will be  the best programmer in the world. ");
```

А вот так нет.

```
 wstring expression = L"My name is Kolia"+L"I am form Ukiraine."+L"I study at MIT univerisy."+L"I will be  the best programmer in the world. ";
```

Comment: Потому что текст в кавычках - это обычные массивы символов, а не `wstring`. Попробуйте так: `wstring(L"foo") + L"bar" + L"baz"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что первый член - не `wstring`.

Вот так

```
wstring expression = wstring(L"My name is Kolia")+L"I am form Ukiraine."+L"I study at MIT univerisy."+L"I will be  the best programmer in the world. ";
```

вполне работает...

P.S. А что, в Массачусетском технологическом это не проходят? :)

Comment: Может и проходят. Но я там, на жаль, не учусь потому и спрашиваю. Спасибо у меня все работе.

Comment: Ну, вы же написали *I study at MIT univerisy.* :) Кстати, ни к С, ни к winapi вопрос отношения не имеет, так что эти метки вы зря указали...

Comment: но я много чего могу написать.Да я добавил их ,чтобы быстрее получить ответ на свой вопрос. Так как там люди тоже могут оказаться, что знакомы с темой. И еще когда я написал MIT имел ввиду Melbourne Institute of Technology.